# VT-x and 32 bit restrictions in VBox

Tags: virtualbox

I am having a problem in Virtual Box. I can only create 32 bit VM's, I am running windows 10-64 bit so this should NOT be happening. And also whenever I run a new VM I get this.

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine kali.
>
> VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes
>   (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
>
> Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005) Component: ConsoleWrap Interface:
>   IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

But I know for a fact that I have Intel VT-d/x enabled. Any suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This error arises due to virtualisation is disabled by your operating system. So:

1. Go into the BIOS setup (by repeatedly pressing F10 or F2 or F9 depends upon your motherboard while your system is booting)
2. Click the Advance option.
3. Find virtualisation in the list.
4. Make sure it's enabled .
5. To save the changes you have done press F10.

Now probably you will not encounter the same problem in virtual box when you run it.